# Add MathJax support to chat

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should chat have TeX support?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support)

Adding MathJax support to chat would be really helpful sometimes. Don't know what a performance impact that might mean though...

Comment: Related question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support